# Can't sync site config from git, entities exist of type x

Tags: 8, configuration

For whatever reason I seem unable to find a good resource to explain syncing the actual structure of a site (like blocks and configs).
I'm using git currently and am doing local development using lando. I have just been using the same folder this whole time but recently had to do some things and needed to clone my repo.
I've got the site running but it's back to the "defualt" state and made me install drupal and such.

I have the `config/sync` folder but cannot use `drush cim` or sync via the UI.

```
The configuration cannot be imported because it failed validation for the following reasons:
Entities exist of type Taxonomy term and Vocabulary Blog Categories. These entities need to be deleted before importing.
Entities exist of type Shortcut link and Shortcut set Default. These entities need to be deleted before importing.
Entities exist of type Paragraph and Paragraph type Webform + Content. These entities need to be deleted before importing.
Entities exist of type Paragraph and Paragraph type Standard Content. These entities need to be deleted before importing.
Entities exist of type Content and Content type Page. These entities need to be deleted before importing.
Entities exist of type Content and Content type Homepage. These entities need to be deleted before importing.
Unable to install the Commerce Store module since it requires the Path alias module.
Unable to install the Commerce Number Pattern module since it requires the Path alias module.
Unable to install the Commerce Order module since it requires the Path alias module.
Unable to install the Commerce Product module since it requires the Path alias module.
Unable to install the Commerce Cart module since it requires the Path alias module.
Unable to install the Commerce Checkout module since it requires the Path alias module.
Unable to uninstall the Path alias module since the Path module is installed.
Unable to uninstall the Path alias module since the Pathauto module is installed.
```

This is spat out by the UI.
I had tried to do something with the `uuid` but it obviously didn't work. I'll say that's because, again, I can't seem to find a good explanation of how this actually works.

Comment: "For whatever reason I seem unable to find a good resource to explain syncing the actual structure of a site (like blocks and configs)."

The reason is that the Drupal documentation is horrendous, and the structure of a Drupal site is a tangle of bizarre, misguided, and self-defeating ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things are happening:

1. In your active configuration in the database, some module(s) is/are installed, that isn't/aren't installed in the configuration you are trying to import. The problem is that you have content for the thing(s) being uninstalled, so if you were to import the configuration, you'd have ghosts in your database. These ghosts are listed in the errors that begin with 'Entities exist of of type X'.

   To resolve this you'll need to either enable the missing item(s) in the configuration you're trying to import, or you'll need to delete the items from the database before you import your configuration.
2. The configuration you are trying to import has enabled modules, but the codebase for those modules does not exist in the Drupal installation you are trying to import the configuration into. These modules are listed at the end of the errors that begin with 'Unable to install the X module' (ex - you are missing the Path Alias code base).

   To resolve this, you'll either need to add the code for the required modules to your codebase.

Comment: Right so those make enough sense on their own. But I can't get it to work. It won't install the commerce because it needs path alias but path alias won't install because of the other path modules.   
Is there no way to force this import? How did this actually happen in the first place?

Comment: You'll need to fix them in the order that they appear in the list. So first fix number 1 that I gave above, then number 2.

Comment: Can't answer as to why it happened at the first place, it will have come from whatever you have done.

Comment: managed to get all the errors gone, then it broke the whole site saying that it can't delete the default language.

Comment: If my answer was what helped you get the errors fixed can you please mark this as the correct answer? You can open a new issue for the new problem that has arisen.